# How do I mock a PouchDb database using Jest and Typescript?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, pouchdb

I would like to write a unit test that uses mocked PouchDb responses, but I'm struggling to get Jest, Typescript and PouchDb to all play together nicely. Admittedly because I don't quite understand all Typescript's ins-and-outs.

I want to mock the following module. Nothing fancy, it reads some global config and returns a new PouchDb instance.

```
import PouchDB from "pouchdb";
export class CouchDbProvider {
    getCouchDb(dbName:string): PouchDB.Database<{}> {
        const config = (window as any).config || (global as any).config; // ('global' is for unit tests)
        const {COUCHDB_URL: couchDbUrl} = config;

        return new PouchDB(
            `${couchDbUrl}${dbName}`,
            {
                skip_setup: true
            });
    }
}
export default new CouchDbProvider();
```

When the abovementioned getCouchDb() function is called, it should return a *mocked PouchDb instance* that I can configure.

And this is where I'm struggling. The part of my unit test code where I attempt to do the mocking looks as follows...

```
import PouchDB from "pouchdb";
import couchDbProvider from "../../providers/couch-db-provider";

jest.mock('../../providers/couch-db-provider')
jest.mock('pouchdb');
const mockedCouchDbProvider = couchDbProvider as jest.Mocked<typeof couchDbProvider>;
const mockedPouchDb = PouchDB as jest.Mocked<typeof PouchDB>;
mockedCouchDbProvider.getCouchDb.mockReturnValue(mockedPouchDb);
```

Typescript compilation fails on the last line with: `TS2345: Argument of type 'Mocked<Static>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Database<{}>'.   Type '{ plugin: MockInstance<Static, ["This should be passed to PouchDB.plugin()"]>; version: string; fetch: MockInstance<Promise<Response>, [string | Request, RequestInit?]>; ... 16 more ...; eventNames: MockInstance<...>; } & Static' is missing the following properties from type 'Database<{}>': find, createIndex, getIndexes, deleteIndex, and 29 more.`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation and prototyping I managed to figure this out. The variable names below can be simplified, but I'll share the code as-is for clarity.

This is how to get Jest, PouchDb and Typescript to play together nicely:

```
import PouchDB from "pouchdb";
import couchDbProvider from "../../providers/my-custom-couch-db-provider";

jest.mock('../../providers/my-custom-couch-db-provider');
jest.mock('pouchdb');
const mockedCouchDbProvider = couchDbProvider as jest.Mocked<typeof couchDbProvider>;

// This is actually creates a **mocked pouchDb instance**. When we told Jest to import the pouchDb module it replaced constructors with ones that creates mocks.
const mockedPouchDbInstance = new PouchDB(); 

// We do this just so we can configure the mock pouchDb's methods in a type safe way.
const mockedPouchDbConfig = mockedPouchDbInstance as jest.Mocked<typeof mockedPouchDbInstance>;

mockedCouchDbProvider.getCouchDb.mockReturnValue(mockedPouchDbInstance);

mockedPouchDbConfig.get.mockResolvedValue(/* etc etc */);
```